# Customizing a TFS 2010 Build process

Tags: tfsbuild

I want to run a console app for every time a build is executed on the TFS server. This app should receive as parameters the path to the latest build sources and binaries. I am not able to figure out which build activity to use for that. There doesn't seem to be enough information online about it as well, or perhaps I dont know what to look for.

Can anyone help with this please?

Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the following blog: http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/?tag=/build+2010+customization?

It has been a while since I have put it together, so I am not sure if your answer is there, but it is a good starting point.